# only select row if next row is not identical

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that has song codes and timestamps. The code represents a song that is playing and the timestamp is when the song was identified to be playing. I need to produce a list of all the codes and their corresponding timestamps, but ONLY the first time they were identified. The major problem is that a song may play multiple times, the only thing that would indicate it is a new instance of the song would be the previous row would contain a different code.

This is my code (which only give the first and last timecodes for each

```
SELECT a.* FROM ap_results a INNER JOIN ( SELECT trackId, MAX(timeplay), timeplay FROM ap_results GROUP BY trackId ) b ON a.trackId = b.trackId AND a.timeplay > b.timeplay WHERE a.trackId <> b.trackId ORDER BY timeplay
```

-

```
╔════╦══════════╦═════════════════════╦══╗
║ id ║ trackId  ║      playTime       ║  ║
╠════╬══════════╬═════════════════════╬══╣
║  1 ║ 42390-01 ║ 2016-02-01 01:00:00 ║  ║
║  2 ║ 42390-01 ║ 2016-02-01 01:01:00 ║  ║
║  3 ║ 42390-01 ║ 2016-02-01 01:01:25 ║  ║
║  4 ║ 54212-04 ║ 2016-02-01 01:01:30 ║  ║
║  5 ║ 54212-04 ║ 2016-02-01 01:01:59 ║  ║
║  6 ║ 42390-01 ║ 2016-02-01 01:02:08 ║  ║
║  7 ║ 12899-03 ║ 2016-02-01 01:07:02 ║  ║
║  8 ║ 12899-03 ║ 2016-02-01 01:07:26 ║  ║
║  9 ║ 42390-01 ║ 2016-02-01 01:08:10 ║  ║
╚════╩══════════╩═════════════════════╩══╝
```

I need a query to display the following:

```
42390-01 - 2016-02-01 01:00:00
54212-04 - 2016-02-01 01:01:30
42390-01 - 2016-02-01 01:02:08
12899-03 - 2016-02-01 01:07:02
42390-01 - 2016-02-01 01:08:10
```

Comment: You have both `mysql` and `sql-server` tagged here and it's probably not both that you are using at the same time. Which RDBMS is it?

Comment: please always mention database version. and as said mention sq-server or mysql

Comment: sorry, its just mysql

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for in not easily obtainable with sql beacuse is a procedural result ..

the following are a some brief suggestion (in pesudo code because i don't in which server side language you work) for obtain you result by a procedural approach server side ..

```
connect your db 

get all the rows in order of timeplay 

set the firts rows in a var (actRow) and in an array of result rows (resultRows[])

loop over these rows starting from the second  {
     if the actual in loop  row trackId is not the same of actRow. {
             store/add this row in resultRows // for final result 
             and set the var for row with this value
      }
}

show  the resultRows
```

Comment: that querry only returns the first instances of the song code. If the song plays again later in the day it does not return that result.

Comment: I'sorry but i have understend this is your need. explain better you want the foirts or the last.. timeplay?

Comment: I'm really new to this but it looks like its just grouping all the instances of the trackId and returning the earliest one.

Comment: don' use comment .. try editing the question and format the data properly .. is better ..

Comment: I was trying to insert the table, but that's not working out. So here is an example. A song (Song 1) plays at 10:00 am, this is written to the DB, At 10:01 it is again identified as being played and it this is also written to the DB. At 10:02 a new song (Song 2) is identified as being played and written to the DB and again at 10:03 and again at 10:04. At 10:05 Song 1 plays again and this is written to the DB. At this point there are 5 entries, but I want to show three results to represent each time a song played. at 10:00, 10:02 and 10:05

Comment: In this case my answer in wrong .. i think for this you need a server side elaboration .. with a procedural language..  like PHP Ruby  C# ... give me a feedback so i delete the answer ..

Comment: Is this correct (what a human would do)?
sort by time played, ascending
 
Report tune and time
Examine next. 
If tune is not the same as just reported, report it.
Else, ignore
Examine next.

Comment: Could be but this is not SQL this is procedural ..with a server side language like php is easy.

Comment: if its procedural as you say, I still need some guidance on how to code to do what BryanT is suggesting

Comment: Do you know a procedural server side language like php or c# ..?

Comment: Anyway i have update the answer with  few suggestion in pseudo code for obatin your result ..

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, unfortunately I don't have the experience or knowledge to translate your pseudo code into actual code, but it's set me in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks to you.. and if  my suggestion useful had set you in the right direction you can rate my answer as useful